# Connecting signals to different functions based on combobox selection

Tags: pyqgis, pyqt, qt-designer

I'm working on a Qgis plugin (using QT Designer). The goal of the plugin is, depending on the combobox, clicking on a button will launch different functions.
For example, choosing "Images - WMS" in the combobox and then clicking on the button will use the "import_wms" function. The same goes for "WMTS" and "WFS"...

I've written the code below, at first it's working but when I start changing and pressing it gets buggy and clicking on the button will launch all the function regardless of the combobox.

```
def button_click(self):
    if self.combobox.currentText() == "Images - WMS":
        self.button.clicked.connect(lambda: self.import_wms('agriculture'))
    elif self.combobox.currentText() == "Images tuilées - WMTS":
        self.button.clicked.connect(lambda: self.import_wmts('agriculture'))
    elif self.combobox.currentText() == "Données vecteur - WFS":
        self.button.clicked.connect(lambda: self.import_wfs('agriculture'))
```

I've searched on Google and found that I have to disconnect my the function. I've tried adding this : `self.agri1.clicked.disconnect()` to my code. However, I get this error : `TypeError: disconnect() failed between 'clicked' and all its connections`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of making individual connections for each combobox options, it is more reasonable to connect the button click event to one function which checks the combobox value  and calls the related function as follows:

```
def button_click(self):
    if self.combobox.currentText() == "Images - WMS":
        self.import_wms('agriculture')
    elif self.combobox.currentText() == "Images tuilées - WMTS":
        self.import_wmts('agriculture')
    elif self.combobox.currentText() == "Données vecteur - WFS":
        self.import_wfs('agriculture')
        

self.button.clicked.connect(self.button_click)
```

Comment: I havent thought of that... thank you its perfect ! ;)